# OutOfMemory Exception from LINQ statement only under certain cirumstances

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, exception, out-of-memory

I manage a website with a blogging section consisting of ASP.NET MVC architecture with articles stored in a SQL Server database. It is set up to email me if any exceptions are thrown. Every couple weeks I get a series of emails late at night (generally between 40-150) with the same System.OutOfMemory Exception thrown by this line of code:

```
var resultsDb = db.Articles
    .Where(x => x.CreatedDate <= DateTime.Now 
                && x.ArticleTypeID == TypeID 
                && x.IsActive == true)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate)
    .ToList();
```

Now after doing some research, I understand that querying all articles at once is bad practice and can cause this error (there are currently ~200 articles in the database). However there a couple strange things about the situation that I'm at a loss to explain:

1. No matter what I do I'm unable to reproduce the exception manually. It's slow, but the query always completes successfully in localhost, both with production and development article databases. Also no matter what I do on the live site, I never get an email indicating an error.
2. The timing of the exceptions: Always in relatively large batches spread out over a period of 1-2 exceptions a minute. Always late at night. Only sporadically one night every couple weeks.

I'm very curious about what could be causing these occurrences. Is it a security threat? Something going on with the database?

Thanks!

Comment: It might be some kind of (backup?) job running at your server late at night, reducing the amount of memory available to your application. Another option would be undisposed objects causing a memory leak, but it's unlikely for the circumstances you describe (always late at night, not reproducible).

Comment: If an article contains a large text field you may consider splitting the entity in a light part for querying and the actual content for display that's only pulled from the database when necessary. There's not much we can do here.

Comment: I agree with Compufreak: do an audit of IDisposables in your application code and make sure they're all in using blocks, if not manually disposed. If you're using in-memory session state make sure it's getting clean up properly when sessions time out. It also wouldn't hurt to check the web server logs to see if there's a burst of activity around those times (e.g.: search engine spidering).